# Find and Replace text within all .docm in a folder using VBA incrementing replace variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

Siddharth Rout posted very closely what I am looking for in another post. The only issue is that when the script loops through the files in the directory I need the replace variable to increase. For example, my files are named 001 - Wordfile.docm, 002 - wordfile2.docm, and so on. So for the first file the find would be 001X replace 001X, then loop to next file and find 001X replace 002x, next file 001X replace with 003X and so on. The reason for this is that we duplicate the 001 file 350 times but then need to change the excel links in the word doc to point to the appropriate worksheet in excel. I hope I made this clear and not more complicated. Anyway, here is the code that Sid posted. How can I add to the script to change the replace value while looping through the docs.

```
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
' This code uses Late Binding to connect to word and hence you '
' you don't need to add any references to it                   '
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'

Option Explicit

'~~> Defining Word Constants
Const wdFindContinue As Long = 1
Const wdReplaceAll As Long = 2

Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object, rngStory as Object
    Dim sFolder As String, strFilePattern As String
    Dim strFileName As String, sFileName As String

    '~~> Change this to the folder which has the files
    sFolder = "C:\LQ\"
    '~~> This is the extention you want to go in for
    strFilePattern = "*.docm"

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Loop through the folder to get the word files
    strFileName = Dir$(sFolder & strFilePattern)
    Do Until strFileName = ""
        sFileName = sFolder & strFileName

        '~~> Open the word doc
        Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)

        '~~> Do Find and Replace
        For Each rngStory In oWordDoc.StoryRanges
            With rngStory.Find
                .Text = "001X"
                .Replacement.Text = Left(strFileName,3) & "X"
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next

        '~~> Close the file after saving
        oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True

        '~~> Find next file
        strFileName = Dir$()
    Loop

    '~~> Quit and clean up
    oWordApp.Quit

    Set oWordDoc = Nothing
    Set oWordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With rngStory.Find
   .Text = "001X"
   .Replacement.Text = Left(strFileName,3) & "X"
   .Wrap = wdFindContinue
   .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Comment: I tried running the script above with Ted's change. I get an error in Line 9 Char: 22 Expected '=' 800a03f3 Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who's Ted?  And what's on line 9 of your updated script?  Maybe update your question with the current version.

Comment: Well, the error I receive is Line:9 Char:22 Error: Expected '=' Code: 800a03f3 Source Microsoft VBScript Compilation error

Comment: I just saved it as a .vbs. How do I run a vbscript? Do i have to have visual studio to compile it?

Comment: Thanks Tim! I will give it a shot and let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: How cool is that? You just saved me hours of work Tim! I created a macro in word using the script above and it worked like a champ! Thank you Sir!